# error-The system cannot find the path specified: 'data/train'

Tags: python

```
train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
train_data_dir,
target_size=(img_width,img_height),
batch_size=batch_size,
class_mode='binary'
)
```

this is small piece of code but there is an error in it i.e [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'data/train'
plz help me

Comment: You don't show how you defined the train_data_dir. I recommend that you define it as a full path (in windows 'c:\etc\etc')

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: @Gerry P   at which place i have to provide path of files?

Comment: @Gerry P  this is how i defined train_data_dir            train_data_dir='data/train'